# Hyperlink URL causing resource not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have a label created dynamically that displays content and a local link to files so that these can be downloaded or viewed in a browser.

```
label.Text="..content.." + " <asp:HyperLink runat=\"server\" NavigateUrl=\"~/c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx\">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>";
```

I can use a hyperlink control or an `<a>` tag to display the link in the dynamic label and I can see the link address is basically correct except that Visual Web Developer 2010 Express automatically adds the root path as a prefix

```
http://localhost:50969/website/
```

to the path string followed by the URL I added enclosed inside 2 single quote quotation marks.

```
http://localhost:50969/website/'c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx'
```

When I click the link, the page throws `resource cannot be found` error. I think that the 2 single quotes are causing the error. Is there a way to remove the single quotes? Or is there a better technique to this?

Comment: Could you try `NavigateUrl='~/c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx'` instead of `NavigateUrl=\"~/c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx\"`? Reference: [Server tag not parsed in asp:Hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14130823/6741868)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL This is the resulting url http://localhost:50969/website/'c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx' which is the same and the same error but technically incorrect syntax because the double quote signs the end of the linkbutton start tag.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL There is logic in your suggestion. With manipulation the single quotes are removed. I will keep the post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a asp.net Control as a string to a Label, but that will never work.

Either use the `HyperLink` control correctly by placing it on the aspx page and set the `NavigateUrl` property.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Or create a "normal" hyperlink as a string.

```
label.Text = "..content..<a href=\"~/c/customer/uploads/TestDocument.docx\">HyperLink</a>";
```

Comment: If you read the question properly, you'll see that the control or the link can't be put on the aspx page because it must added dynamically or as a string.